# .htaccess rewrite to force HTTPS, how to avoid some domain names?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force HTTPS for one of my website. Unfortunately I have other websites on my server and I don't want to redirect them to https. I tried to add a rewrite condition but it's not working. Do you know why? My goal is to avoid the https redirection for botletter.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://botletter.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://www.botletter.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using a dynamic configuration file ("`,htaccess`") place that rule set in your http servers host configuration. Things are even faster then. You can create a separate file holding those rules and include it in all virtual host definitions you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# To https www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(botletter\.com|eedart\.co|other\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# To https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(botletter\.com|eedart\.co|other\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# botletter to www.botletter
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(botletter\.com|eedart\.co|other\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Depending on your configuration, you may need to use:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Comment: Thanks, it works! How can I do to add other domain names to avoid? Can I just add a line like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !feedart.co [NC] after RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !botletter.com [NC] (it seems it's not working)